# How to translate entries in rabbitmq.conf (new format) to rabbitmq.config (legacy format)?

Tags: rabbitmq

Rabbitmq from version 3.7 uses 2 formats:

- erlang-style legacy format, used by default in rabbitmq.config file,
- properties-style new format, used by default in rabbitmq.conf file.

https://blog.rabbitmq.com/posts/2018/02/new-configuration-format-in-rabbitmq-3-7/

New options that appear in rabbitmq are often documented only in new format and it is not obvious how to achieve the same setting in the legacy format.

Where can I find such mapping?

Answer (score -1):

That article mentioned in the question says that new format is translated on the fly using [Cuttlefish](https://github.com/Kyorai/cuttlefish) and it uses [rabbit.schema](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/blob/main/deps/rabbit/priv/schema/rabbit.schema) mapping file to control this translation. You can manually find there how new properties are translated to legacy format.

Example:

Because of this line in rabbit.schema

```
{mapping, "heartbeat", "rabbit.heartbeat", [{datatype, integer}]}.
```

we can infer that new format entry

```
heartbeat = 60
```

will translate to legacy format

```
[{
        rabbit, [
                {heartbeat, 60}
        ]
}].
```

See also:

- [new config template](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/blob/main/deps/rabbit/docs/rabbitmq.conf.example)
- [old config template](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/blob/v3.7.x/deps/rabbit/docs/rabbitmq.config.example)